# Xcode does not show the downloaded and installed iOS 12.4 simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode11

I had a specific issue reported in iOS 12.4 in my project and so I wanted to install the iOS 12.4 simulator in Xcode (Xcode 11.5).

I went to the Preferences -> Components and installed iOS Simulator 12.4. It showed the installation successful and shows simulator with a blue checkbox as it is in.

I killed the Xcode and restarted. However, the Simulator is not showing up in the List of simulators for some reason.

Anybody have come across such an issue before?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you find out what was the problem? I have the same issue.

Comment: Not yet. I had to park the issue I was testing because of that.